# how can i get the number of products in each countries using my django models

Tags: python, django, django-views, orm, django-templates

I have a model in Django, I need a way to get the number of products in each country so that I can use that to plot a graph.

**NB**: I am using the django-countries package in my application

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
```

I want the result to be something like:
US: 5
NG: 20
SA: 8

and so on, so I could use it to plot graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Product.objects.values('country').annotate(
    number=Count('pk')
).order_by('country')
```

This will make a `QuerySet` that looks like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'country': 'NG', 'number': 20},
    {'country': 'SA', 'number': 8},
    {'country': 'US', 'number': 5}
]>
```

We can convert this to a dictionary that maps the countries to the corresponding number with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = Product.objects.values('country').annotate(
    number=Count('pk')
).order_by('country')

result = {
    q['country']: q['number']
    for q in qs
}
```